# How do you determine when to drop the +/- after solving an IVP Homogenous Linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

my question is on how (and when) to drop the +/- in front of a square root after solving a homogenous linear ODE.

Given the equation
$$
xyy'= y^2-x^2
$$
with
$$
y(-1)=2,
$$
I solved it to get
$$
y = \pm x\sqrt {c - 2 \ln|x|}.
$$ 
So far, so good.

Plugging in the value of x = -1, I get
$$
2=\pm(-1)\sqrt{c}. 
$$
Clearly squaring both sides gives c=4.

Plugging c back into the general solution, I get 
$$
y = \pm x\sqrt {4 - 2 \ln|x|}.
$$

However, the solution in the book I'm using drops the positive answer and just leaves it as negative. Can anyone help me understand why this is so?

Thank you!!

Matt

Comment: Thank you - first post ever, still learning the syntax :).

Comment: No problem Matt

Comment: This has nothing to do with the differential equation as such. Only $y =- x\sqrt {4 - 2 \ln|x|}$ actually satisfies $y(-1)=2$ given that the square root is always positive.

Comment: "Given that the square root is always positive" - why can't the square root also be negative?

Comment: Because that is how it is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root). This is why $\pm$ is put in front when removing squares on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the two particular solutions :

First :
$$y = + x\sqrt {4 - 2 \ln|x|}.$$ 
$y(-1)= (-1)\sqrt {4 - 2 \ln|-1|}=-\sqrt{4}=-2$

This doesn't satisfy the condition $y(-1)=2$. 
Thus this solution is rejected.
$$ $$

Second :
$$y = - x\sqrt {4 - 2 \ln|x|}.$$ 
$y(-1)= -(-1)\sqrt {4 - 2 \ln|-1|}=\sqrt{4}=2$

This satisfies the condition $y(-1)=2$. 
Thus this is the correct solution.